# How can I plot a unit circle to depict the unit vector?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, math, graph

A unit vector builds a unit circle around the origin. I have the code for plotting a unit vector in python, but that only plots the vector with its direction and does not create a unit circle.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

V = np.array([[1,1], [-2,2], [4,-7]])
origin = np.array([[0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0]]) 

plt.quiver(*origin, V[:,0], V[:,1], color=['r','b','g'], scale=21)
plt.show()
```

How can I plot a unit circle using a unit vector at the origin?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how the scale works, but this might help as a starting point;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

circle1 = plt.Circle((0, 0), 1/21, fill=False)

V = np.array([[1,1], [-2,2], [4,-7]])
origin = np.array([[0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0]]) 

plt.quiver(*origin, V[:,0], V[:,1], color=['r','b','g'], scale=21 )

ax.add_patch(circle1)

plt.show()
```